# How to insert a supplementary section between chapters?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, books

I am using the book class and after every five chapters (out of 20) I want a review section (so four review sections total).  This review section should appear with the prominence of a chapter in the table of contents (same indentation, font weight and size, etc.) but it should not affect the chapter numbering - it should have it's own numbering like "Review 1" and it should show up as "Review 1" in the table of contents.  How can I accomplish this?

```
   \documentclass{book}

   \begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \chapter{Chapt. 1}
   \chapter{Chapt. 2}
   \chapter{Chapt. 3}
   \chapter{Chapt. 4}
   \chapter{Chapt. 5}
   \chapter{Review 1} % this should be a review "section" b/w chapters 5 and 6
   \chapter{Chapt. 6}
   \chapter{Chapt. 7}
   \chapter{Chapt. 8}
   \chapter{Chapt. 9}
   \chapter{Chapt. 10}
   \chapter{Review 2} % this should be a review "section" b/w chapters 10 and 11
   \chapter{Chapt. 11}
   \chapter{Chapt. 12}
   \chapter{Chapt. 13}
   \chapter{Chapt. 14}
   \chapter{Chapt. 15}
   \chapter{Review 3} % this should be a review "section" b/w chapters 15 and 16
   \chapter{Chapt. 16}
   \chapter{Chapt. 17}
   \chapter{Chapt. 18}
   \chapter{Chapt. 19}
   \chapter{Chapt. 20}
   \chapter{Review 4} % this should be a review "section" after chapter 20

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\setcounter{chapter}{0}` command before each your "Review" chapter and then reset the counter.
Also use `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Review x}` for toc.

```
  \documentclass{book}

   \begin{document}
   \tableofcontents
   \chapter{Chapt. 1}
   \chapter{Chapt. 2}
   \chapter{Chapt. 3}
   \chapter{Chapt. 4}
   \chapter{Chapt. 5}
   \setcounter{chapter}{0}
   \chapter*{Review 1} % this should be a review "section" b/w chapters 5 and 6
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Review 1}
   \setcounter{chapter}{5}
   \chapter{Chapt. 6}
   \chapter{Chapt. 7}
   \chapter{Chapt. 8}
   \chapter{Chapt. 9}
   \chapter{Chapt. 10}
   \setcounter{chapter}{0}
   \chapter*{Review 2} % this should be a review "section" b/w chapters 10 and 11
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Review 2}
   \setcounter{chapter}{10}
   \chapter{Chapt. 11}
   \chapter{Chapt. 12}
   \chapter{Chapt. 13}
   \chapter{Chapt. 14}
   \chapter{Chapt. 15}
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
   \chapter*{Review 3} % this should be a review "section" b/w chapters 15 and 16
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Review 3}
   \setcounter{chapter}{15}
   \chapter{Chapt. 16}
   \chapter{Chapt. 17}
   \chapter{Chapt. 18}
   \chapter{Chapt. 19}
   \chapter{Chapt. 20}
       \setcounter{chapter}{0}
   \chapter*{Review 4} % this should be a review "section" b/w chapters 10 and 11
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Review 4}
 % \setcounter{chapter}{15}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: This works well.  What if I want to include "Review 2 Functions on the Real Line" in the table of contents?  If I add all of that to \addcontentsline{toc} then the spacing doesn't line up with the titles of the other chapters.

Comment: Suppose Chapter 5 ends on an odd page.  Then Review 1 would start on the next odd page, so there would be a blank page in between.  This blank page should have the previous chapters header, which it does, but the numbering also gets reset there. Edit:  Maybe \cleardoublepage before the counter is reset would work.